# Umbraco 8 - Upload and Embed Videos from Local File

Tags: tinymce, umbraco, umbraco8, video-embedding

What I'm trying to achieve is to upload a video to the Media section in Umbraco 8 CMS and embed then choose the video to embed in Content, just like what is normally done with images. The video can be .mp4/.avi etc.

Looks like Umbraco 8 only supports YouTube and Vimeo videos, but that's not ideal in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Umbraco 8 supports a lot more than YouTube and Vimeo out of the box: https://our.umbraco.com/apidocs/v8/csharp/api/Umbraco.Web.Media.EmbedProviders.html

If there IS an external provider you'd like to use, but it isn't in the list above, it's possible to create your own embed provider to make the Embed dialog support it. As long as it supports OEmbed it shouldn't be crazy complicated to do, I think. Have a look here: https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/extending/Embedded-Media-Provider/

In case you are simply not able to use an external video service, you probably have to do something like what is mentioned here: https://our.umbraco.com/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/84626-inserting-video-banners-in-umbraco (in short, create a Media Picker property on your document type and handle it in the template like Micha describes)

Comment: Good to know that Umbraco supports more than just YouTube and Vimeo! I wanted to embed videos like images in the RichTextEditor. Eventually I used the way Micha described to embed the video at a predefined place.

Comment: Glad to hear you found a way :-) If you think my answer helped you, don't forget to mark it as a solution ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In umbracoSettings.config file there's a section disallowedUploadFiles.  Is Mp4 in there?  You should be able to do this

There is also a max file size, so maybe check your vide is under that as well

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I didn't explain well in the question that I wanted to embed videos like images in the RichTextEditor. Yes I was able to the upload Mp4 as files and also increased the max file size.